# Devexpress Aspx Gridview Control. Don't want to show any rows until at least one filter is applied

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, devexpress

I am currently developing a C# based asp.net page.

I am using the Devexpress Aspx Gridview control to allow users to filter various data on my asp.net web page.  Some examples of such data include users profiles and articles written by the user.

What I want is to be able to have my gridview control not return any rows until at least one filter parameter is entered by the user.  The reason for this is that I want the control to appear to the end user to be an advanced search more than a filter and I do not want to arbitrarily give preference to the first couple of entries returned by the data source.

Is there any way to accomplish this, either via javascript or c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Selecting event of the SQLDataSource works ideally for me:

```
protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = ASPxGridView1.FilterExpression == string.Empty;
}
```